# Building shared library using another shared library in linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a shared library A which uses shared library B, and an application P which relies on A.

I don't want to link P against A and B, but to link P against A only, and A against B (and somehow hide B to P)

How can I do ?

The shared libraries are generated with 'g++ -shared...'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need B to be a standalone shared library - which can be used on it's own, don't build it as a shared library, instead build a static library with the code complied with `-fPIC` - then link this static library to the shared library A.

If you need a shared library of B as well, then use the same objects to build a shared library.